# spring security filter-chain regex pattern

Tags: regex, path, spring-security

In my application which uses spring security I want to define two different areas both using their own spring security filter-chain. My question is: is it possible to define two regex expressions as follows:

1. every path starting with /foobar/*
2. every other path not starting with /foobar

The important part here is that the second path should also match if somewhere within it, but not in the beginning, it cotains the /foobar/ string.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^/foobar/.*$
```

will match if the path starts with `/foobar/`;

```
^(?!/foobar/).*$
```

will match any path that doesn't start with `/foobar/`  (`(?!...)` is a so-called [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).